# Load content from a dynamically loaded module with MEF

Tags: silverlight, mef, modularity

I'm working on a **modular Silverlight application** and in one of the modules I'd like to display an image on a view. I've added the image file under the module project in the `/Resources/Images` directory. And than I've changed the image file's `Build Action` property to `Content`. I think it's nicer **not to embed** the image into the dll file. The xap file after build contains the image.

In the View xaml I've inserted the image `<Image Source="/Resources/Images/Yoda.jpg" />` and design time it displays correctly but **runtime the image is missing**.

**My question is how to solve this problem?** I don't want to embed in the dll (Build Action: Resource).

I've made a small test solution if you want to play with it:
[Solution.zip](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0H1ZROz-b5NX0tOUXhIaFByMGc/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance

Design time the image displayed correctly:
[image: Design time the image displayed correctly]

But runtime the image is missing:
[image: At runtime the image is missing]

Solution structure:

[image: Solution structure]

Answer (score 0):

You could set the **Copy to Output Directory** property of the image to either:

- Copy always, or
- Copy if newer

Then at runtime it will be available.